# Relações muitos para muitos em serviço RESTful

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, rest, asp.net-web-api

Estou começando a trabalhar com serviços RESTful e estou com dúvidas sobre relações muitos para muitos. Por exemplo, suponha que eu tenha duas entidades `Cliente` e `Fornecedor` e que `Cliente` possua uma lista de fornecedores, os fornecedores dos quais ele compra e `Fornecedor` possua uma lista de clientes que compram dele. Algo assim

```
public class Cliente
{
    // Propriedades da classe Cliente

   public IList<Fornecedor> Fornecedores { get; set; }
}

public class Fornecedor
{
    // Propriedades da classe Fornecedor

   public IList<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
}
```

Daí se quiser expor isso num serviço RESTful qual seria a melhor forma de fazer? Pensei em expor a seguinte URL `/clientes/{idCliente}/fornecedores` pra obter os fornecedores de um cliente e então adicionar ou remover fornecedores desse cliente, mas estou achando isso um opção ruim.

Basicamente porque já existiria a url `/fornecedores` que gerencia os fornecedores em geral e colocando essa pros fornecedores de cada cliente me parece muito estranho.

Dessa forma qual o jeito mais indicado de gerenciar relações muitos para muitos em api's restful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nao vejo problema nenhum com a proposta sugerida.

O facto de existirem duas URIs `/clientes/id/fornecedores` e `/fornecedores` nao me parece estranho. Na verdade, e' um modo comum de gerir este tipo de relacoes, como por exemplo, `/posts` + `/authors/id/posts`, `/questions` + `users/id/questions`...

Em REST e' importante que as URIs sejam auto-descritivas. Logo, a maneira mais natural de descrever "obter os fornecedores do cliente 123" seria `GET /clientes/123/fornecedores/`. De modo semelhante, a maneira mais natural de descrever "obter os clientes do fornecedor *abc*" seria `GET /fornecedores/abc/clientes/`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @dcastro. E ao implementar isso no ASP.NET Web API é recomendável colocar os métodos pra lidar com os objetos relacionados a certo objeto no controller desse objeto ou fazer um controller novo? Nesse caso, isso seria colocar os métodos pra lidar com os fornecedores no `ClientesController` ao inves de criar um controller diferente.

Comment: @user1620696 Hm ja vi das duas maneiras... Pessoalmente, se os metodos forem simples, eu criaria um metodo `GetFornecedores` no controller `ClientesController` para a uri `clientes/id/fornecedores`. Se a logica for complexa, talvez valha a pena separar os metodos da "nested resource" para o seu proprio controlador (ex, `FornecedoresDeClientesController`).

Answer (score 1):

Eu simplificaria as coisas na api:
/Clientes/{id}
/Fornecedores{id}?cliente={idcliente}

Tome cuidado com relações muitos para muitos. Se você ainda não conhece, talvez possa tirar algum proveito de algumas práticas do [DDD](http://dddcommunity.org/learning-ddd/what_is_ddd/), onde existe uma clara separação entre assuntos do domínio cujo ciclo de vida são independentes. Neste caso, você poderia utilizar Aggregates para separar estas partes.